# Remote System projects in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ssh, eclipse-plugin, remote-access

I've two requirements,

1. I have added a Remote connection (SSH/SFTP Files) in Remote Systems (RSE) tab, Eclipse. 
   But when I try to open resources (Command + Shift + R), I cannot see files from the remote systems unless I run Synchronize cache.
   I do not want to run Synchronize cache as I need to open directly from remote system to get the latest one.
   So each time, I manually navigate into the remote folders to open them.
2. I want to add one of that remote system folder as Class path, from where my perl modules should be referred.

Any idea on how to do these things in Eclipse?

Comment: Please post what have you achieved so far and the issue you are facing. Please refer to this post for more information https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: That is my question actually, what should I need to do. I haven't done anything other than adding the remote connection to eclipse RSE. In Remote Systems tab, I can see the folder hierarchy from which I can open the file. But the pain is that I need to navigate into the sub folders manually. If the files get listed in the 'Open Resources' tab, that could be much helpful.